# Existence of a $p$-th root for an invertible matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $p$ be a positive integer and $M\in Gl_n(\bf C)$
>
> Find some $A\in M_n(\bf C)$ such that $A^p=M$

This problem got me stumped. I can't even deal with $p=2$ (except when $M$ is a positive definite matrix)...

Comment: Have you tried Jordan normal form + power series?

Comment: @Batman I've never learnt Jordan decomposition (I guess I should since it pops up in a lot of answers here).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a method not (explicitly) using Jordan normal form.

We use the following theorem:

> For any $A \in GL_n(\Bbb C)$, there is a matrix $X \in M_n(\Bbb C)$ such that $\exp(X) = A$, where $\exp(X) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac 1{k!}X^k$ denotes the *matrix exponential*.

If we can use this, then we immediately have
$$
\left(\exp\left(\frac 1p X\right)\right)^p = \exp(X) = A
$$
So that $\exp\left(\frac 1p X\right)$ is a $p$th root of $A$.

That being said, I have not seen a proof of this theorem that does *not* use Jordan canonical form.

Comment: I know this theorem, I even know a proof that doesn't resort to Jordan normal form. How did it occur to you that it would eventually yield a solution ? This is like pulling a rabbit out of your hat.

Comment: Well if I told you, that would ruin the trick :P.  The short answer is that when you take a small look into Lie Groups/Algebras as I have, you quickly learn that the exponential map is particularly magical.

Comment: If you could give me a reference for that proof, by the way, I would appreciate it.

Comment: There's also a nice intuition from the complex numbers, over which we define arbitrary powers of a number by $$ z^\alpha = e^{\alpha \ln(z)} $$

Comment: You can find the proof in there: http://www.amazon.fr/Exercices-math%C3%A9matiques-Oraux-x-ens-alg%C3%A8bre/dp/2842251423  You can find 3 lousy screenshots here http://imgur.com/VRD738X,tuidDln,ygzXEFL#0 . I'll texify it if you can't read French.

Comment: That will do. I have seen something like this, but somehow I forgot how to prove 1 without Jordan Canonical form.  Thank you