# Proof that $x \in \Bbb C[x]/\langle p(x)\rangle$ has a square root

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, alternative-proof

I'm looking for a "nice" proof of the following result.

> **Proposition:** Let $p \in \Bbb C[x]$ be such that $p(0) \neq 0$. Prove that there exists a $q \in \Bbb C[x]$ such that
> $$
> q(x)^2 = x \pmod {p(x)}.
> $$
> In other words, $x + \langle p\rangle \in \Bbb C[x]/\langle p\rangle$ is a perfect square.

Here is a proof that I don't find particularly nice.

Let $V = \Bbb C[x]/\langle p\rangle$; note that $V$ is a finite-dimensional vector space. The multiplication operator $T:V \to V$ define by $[Tf](x) = xf(x)$ defines an invertible linear operator. By various means (cf. [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1318694/81360) or [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1218854/81360)), it can be shown that there exists an operator $S:V \to V$ for which $S = q(T)$ for some $q \in \Bbb C[x]$ and $S^2 = T$. It follows that $[q + \langle p\rangle]^2 = x + \langle p\rangle$.

This proof relies on linear-algebraic machinery, and in particular on Jordan normal form. Is there a nicer approach, perhaps one that is "purely algebraic"?

---

Here's a formal extension of Eric's "explicit" construction. With the application of the Chinese remainder theorem and the substitution $y = x-a$, the problem is reduced to that of showing that $y + a$ has a square root modulo $y^n$. We can see that such a square root exists as follows. Define
$$
q(y) = b_0 + b_1 y + \cdots + b_{n-1} y^{n-1}.
$$
We find that the coefficients of $q^2$ are given by the "Cauchy product", i.e.
$$
q(y)^2 = b_0^2 + (2b_0b_1) y + (2b_0b_2 + b_1^2)y^2 + \cdots + (2b_{n-1}b_0 + \cdots)y^{n-1} \pmod{y^n}.
$$
Define $a_j$ to be the coefficient of $y^j$ in the above product. We note that for $j \geq 1,$
$$
a_j = 2b_0b_j + f_j(b_0,\dots,b_{j-1}).
$$
If we take $b_0 = \sqrt{a} \neq 0$, we then get $a_0 = a$ as desired and find that the system
$$
a_1 = 1, \quad a_j = 0 \text{ for } j \geq 2,
$$
can be solved recursively by taking
$$
b_1 = \frac 1{2b_0}, \quad b_j = -\frac{f_j(b_0,\dots,b_{j-1})}{2b_0} \text{ for } j \geq 2.
$$
Thus, there indeed exists a polynomial $q(y)$ for which $[q(y)]^2 = x + a$, which was what we wanted.

Comment: Jordan normal form seems awfully "algebraic" to me.  In particular, the existence of Jordan normal form in this case is nothing more than the fundamental theorem of algebra together with the Chinese remainder theorem.

Comment: @EricWofsey That's a fair point, I guess "algebraic" is the wrong adjective here. It's hard to say exactly what I mean by "nice" then.

Comment: @EricWofsey Also, thanks for the reminder that Jordan form is really just PID decomposition together with the Chinese remainder theorem. That's a presentation I skimmed through in Dummit and Foote but I had completely forgotten about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, this isn't really any different from using Jordan normal form, but here's how I'd think about it.  By the Chinese remainder theorem, the quotient $\mathbb{C}[x]/(p(x))$ splits as a product of $\mathbb{C}[x]$-algebras of the form $\mathbb{C}[x]/((x-a)^n)$, where the $a$'s are the roots of $p$ and the $n$'s are their multiplicities.  So, it suffices to show that $x$ is a square in $\mathbb{C}[x]/((x-a)^n)$ if $a\neq 0$.  Or, setting $y=x-a$, it sufffices to show that $y+a$ is a square in $\mathbb{C}[y]/(y^n)$.  This follows immediately from the fact that $a$ is a square in $\mathbb{C}$ and Hensel's lemma.  Explicitly, you can construct a square root of $y+a$ by starting with $b\in\mathbb{C}$ that is a square root of $a$, then taking $\frac{y}{2b}+b$ to get a linear term of $y$ when you square it, then adding a quadratic term to make the quadratic term of the square vanish, and so on up to the $y^{n-1}$ term.

Comment: You're right that it is in a sense equivalent, but I like the fact that constructing a square-root of a Jordan matrix is replaced with an application of Hensel's lemma. I'm going to keep the question open for a while longer in case there are any other ideas, but thank you for this answer.