# For nilpotent matrix $N$ over complex field, and for natural number $r$ show that there exists $A$ in $M_n(\mathbb{C})$ s.t. $A^r = N + I_n$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, nilpotence

I have been given as an exercise the following statement to prove, but I have no idea where to start and how to go about proving it.

> If $N$ is a nilpotent matrix in $M_n(\mathbb{C})$ and $r$ is a natural number, prove that there exists $A$ in $M_n(\mathbb{C})$ s.t.
> \begin{align*}
> A^r = N + I_n.
> \end{align*}

Any help will be much appreciated.

(btw we have just been taught the primary decomposition theorem and the Jordan canonical form.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an approach that uses Jordan canonical form. To begin, consider the case where $N \in M_n(\Bbb C)$ is a single Jordan block associated with $0$.

Denote $J_1 = J_1^{(n)} = \text{Id} + N$, which is the Jordan block of the same shape associated with $1$. Note that $J_1^r$ is similar to $J_1$. To see that this is the case, compute
$$
J_1^n = \pmatrix{1 & \binom{n}1 & \binom n2 & \cdots\\
0 & 1 & \binom n1 & \vdots\\
\vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \binom n1\\
0 & \cdots & 0 & 1 }
$$
where $\binom nk$ denotes a [binomial coefficent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient). Note that $J_1^r$ has $1$ as its only eigenvalue and that the rank of $J_1^r - \text{Id}$ is equal to $n-1$. Conclude that the only possible Jordan form for $J_1^r$ is $J_1$.

Thus, there exists an invertible matrix $P$ such that $PJ_1^rP^{-1} = J_1$. However, this means that $(PJ_1P^{-1})^r = J_1$. Thus, the matrix $A_0^{(n)} := PJ_1P^{-1}$ satisfies $[A_0^{(n)}]^r = J_1^{(n)}$.

Now, consider an arbitrary nilpotent $N$. Note that $\text{Id} + N$ has 1 as its only eigenvalue, so its Jordan form can be written as
$$
Q^{-1}(\text{Id} + N)Q = \pmatrix{J_1^{(n_1)}\\ & \ddots\\ && J_1^{(n_k)}}
$$
for suitable $n_1,\dots,n_k$ with $n_1 + \cdots + n_k = n$. This Jordan-form matrix has an $r$-th root: denote
$$
\tilde A = \pmatrix{A_0^{(n_1)}\\ & \ddots \\ && A_0^{(n_k)}}.
$$
Verify that $\tilde A^r = Q^{-1}(\text{Id} + N)Q$. Thus, we have
$$
[Q \tilde A Q^{-1}]^r = \text{Id} + N.
$$
Thus, we have proved the desired result with $A = Q \tilde A Q^{-1}$.

---

An interesting alternative approach via the exponential map:

We can show that $\exp$ defines a bijection between the nilpotent and unipotent matrices. In particular, it suffices to consider the power series definitions of $\exp$ and $\ln$ in order to show that the functions $N \mapsto \exp(N) - I_n$ and $N \mapsto \ln(I_n + N)$ are inverse functions over the set of nilpotent matrices, noting that all power series over $N$ are finite by the nilpotency of $N$.

From there, we may find a nilpotent matrix $M$ such that $\exp(M) = \text{Id} + N$. The properties of the matrix expoenential ensure that $A = \exp(M/r)$ satisfies $A^r = \exp(M) = \text{Id} + N$, which is what we wanted.

---

A possible approach that avoids Jordan canonical form:

**Outline:** Suppose that $N^{k-1} \neq 0$ and $N^k = 0$. Take $A = \text{Id} + a_1 N + a_2 N^2 + \cdots + a_{k-1}N^{k-1}$. Expand $A^r$ and argue that there exist $a_1,\dots,a_{k-1} \in \Bbb C$ such that $A^r = \text{Id} + N$.

The argument for $r = 2$ would go along the lines of [what I've laid out here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3958560/81360).

Comment: I'm sorry but could you explain about what you mean by the Jordan block associated with 0 (or 1) ?

Comment: @Nierdo The size-$n$ Jordan block associated with $\lambda$ is
$$
\pmatrix{\lambda & 1\\
&\lambda & 1\\
&&\ddots & \ddots\\
&&&0}
$$

Comment: one last question, how can I show that based on the rank of $(J_1)^r - Id$, $(J_1)^r$'s only possible Jordan form is $J_1$ ?

Comment: @Nierdo For a matrix $A$ of size $n$, $n - \text{rank}(A - \lambda I)$ (i.e. the dimension of the eigenspace of $A$ associated with $\lambda$) is the number of Jordan blocks associated with $\lambda$ that $A$ has in its Jordan normal form.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a quick solution using the binomial series. Define $A$ by

$$ A = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \binom{1/r}{k} N^k. \tag{1} $$

Here, $ \binom{a}{k} = \frac{a(a-1)\cdots(a-k+1)}{k!}$, where $a \in \mathbb{C}$ and $k \in \{0, 1, \ldots\}$, denotes the generalized binomial coefficient. Since $N$ is nilpotent, the above series is actually a finite sum and hence is well-defined. Moreover,

\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{a}{i}\binom{b}{n-i}
&= \binom{a+b}{n} \tag{2}
\end{align*}

continues to hold for arbitrary $a, b \in \mathbb{C}$ and $n \in \{0, 1, \ldots\}$. Using $\text{(2)}$ repeatedly, we get

\begin{align*}
A^r
&= \sum_{l=0}^{\infty} \sum_{\substack{k_1+\cdots+k_r=l \\ k_1, \ldots, k_r \geq 0 }} \binom{1/r}{k_1}\cdots\binom{1/r}{k_r} N^l \\
&= \sum_{l=0}^{\infty} \binom{1}{l} N^l \\
&= I + N,
\end{align*}